# "list" plugin does not exist after upgrading from Drupal 8.3.x to 8.4.2

Tags: 8

How can I tell exactly what is missing and from which module? (I assume it's `draggableviews`)

How can I remedy this error - or is it in the hands of a contrib module developer or where can I go to see how to contribute the missing plugin?

This is the output of `drush @badev updb`.

```
 ---------------- --------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Module           Update ID                         Type            Description                                                              
 ---------------- --------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  draggableviews   8104                              hook_update_n   Implements hook_update().                                                
  comment          enable_comment_admin_view         post-update     Enable the comment admin view.                                           
  dblog            convert_recent_messages_to_view   post-update     Replace 'Recent log messages' with a view.                               
  field            remove_handler_submit_setting     post-update     Remove the stale 'handler_submit' setting for entity_reference fields.   
  node             configure_status_field_widget     post-update     Load all form displays for nodes, add status with these settings, save.  
  system           classy_message_library            post-update     Clear caches to ensure Classy's message library is always added.         
  system           field_type_plugins                post-update     Force field type plugin definitions to be cleared.   @see                
                                                                     https:www.drupal.orgnode2403703                                          
  views            revision_metadata_fields          post-update     Fix table names for revision metadata fields.                            
 ---------------- --------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

 Do you wish to run the specified pending updates? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > yes

 [notice] Executing draggableviews_update_8104
 [error]  The "list" plugin does not exist. 
 [ok] Performing draggableviews_update_8104
Array   Array
 [success] Cache rebuild complete.
 [success] Finished performing updates.
Connection to drupal8vm.dev closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is solved now. I think that there was a mismatch between the PHP/ Drush / Drupal 8.4.3 versions.

This confused me so I include a table below of what is now working for me. I used it as a checklist to ensure that I had both a dev Drupal 8.3.7 and a dev Drupal 8.4.3 running in parallel.

Despite what the documentation says I think Drush 8.1.15 is not suitable for Drupal 8.4.3 and yes, there are some Drush 9.0.0-rc1 commands that don't work as expected  - like dumping SQL and redirecting SQL files to `drush sqlc` -  but it is workable.

Bits and pieces in each of existing and future Drupal

```
               iMac               MacBook                
PHP VM         7.1.12             7.1.12              
PHP Host       7.1.12             7.1.12
Drush VM       8.1.16-dev         ~9.0     
Drush Host     8.1.15             ~9.0            
Drupal Core    8.3.7              8.4.3
MySQL          5.7.20             5.7.20   (Required MySQL 5.5.3/MariaDB 5.5.20)
```